# Why can a Word Template be changed without saving as new?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I can't figure out why someone can change a MS Word 10 template and not be asked to save as a new file. They are actually able to just click save and it saves over the original which defeats the purpose of the template.

Comment: How is the user opening the template?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple answer to your question is, “Because the author of a template should be allowed to edit it without too much hassle.”  But in my experience this scenario occurs only when the user starts Word and then opens the template with “File” –> “Open” (or “Microsoft icon button” –> “Open”).  If the user just double-clicks on the template, he should be put into a new document, and he will have to save it as a `.doc` or `.docx`.

But the other thing is: he can modify the template only if the OS file permissions allow him to. 
Edit the permissions on the template so people other than you (and any other approved template editors) cannot modify it.